# Selenium chromedriver: How to open latest email in outlook

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to take screenshot of latest email in outlook (OWA) using selenium chromedriver and python code. I am new to selenium so I'm definitely missing how to open element in new window and take screen.

python version: 3.7
headless chrome version: 84.0.4147.89

I am able to login and select latest email. When I try to click() the latest email element it doesnt show any error but when I try to send keys like ENTER to open it in new window, it gives me error saying

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
```

Need inputs as to how I can open the latest email and save it as image.

Code I've used:

```
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
    chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized");
    chrome_options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
    chrome_driver = os.getcwd() + "/chromedriver"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, executable_path=chrome_driver)

    # login part
    driver.get("my OWA url")
    username = driver.find_element_by_id("username")
    password = driver.find_element_by_id("password")
    username.send_keys("my user name")
    password.send_keys("password here")
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.btn").click()

    # To reach to email list and latest email
    latest_email = driver.find_elements_by_id("vr")[0]
    latest_email.click()
    #WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'vr')))
    #latest_email.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    print(latest_email.is_selected())
    print(latest_email.is_displayed())
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.save_screenshot("just_to_see.png")
    driver.close()
```

Above code when executed says element is displayed (true), but false for element is selected. It also shows screen where latest email is selected.

When I uncomment the send keys and WebDriverWait, then it gives error saying `Selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable`

I'd tried other options like like move_to_element() and also by clicking on cData class, but unable to get latest email opened.

Answer (score 0):

If it helps someone, it worked when I used below
`ActionChains(driver).double_click(latest_email).perform()`

Then switched to the new window and iframe which contains the message. Able to get the message..